# Save or discard user changes to object

Tags: c++, oop, architecture, software-design

I have an application where the user can change data on screen in a form (represented as objects in c++ code), and when the user wants to close the window I want to ask if changes should be saved or discarded.

If the user wants to save, the edited object should be persisted to the database and the in-memory object should of course also be up to date.

If the user wants to discard the changes, I want the in-memory object to be restored to its previous state.

I am not sure how to implement this as efficiently as possible, especially the discarding of changes. These are some options I am considering:

1. I create a copy of the in-memory object somewhere in the form logic and change it, and if the user wants to save it I replace the previous in-memory object with the changed one.
2. Same as above but the object somehow stores a copy of itself instead of putting this in the form logic.
3. I keep track of which form fields have changed and only update the relevant object members if the user wants to save (avoiding a potentially large copy operation)?

This seems like such a common thing to do in applications, so maybe there is a standard way to do this, or a design pattern?

Comment: Yes, you operate on a copy. That allows you to easily discard in case of a 'cancel' and you can either `std::swap` the copy with the real object or swap pointers.

Comment: There is certainly more than one way. The choice strongly depends on the size of in-memory-representation as well as the expected amount of changes. E.g. for image processing: You could store the original image, a working copy (to display the result of done work), and the done operations (together with their parameters). This might be much less memory consuming than storing all the intermediate images which leaded to the result. On the other hand, for an undo, you had to remove the last operation from done queue and re-apply the rest to the original image. That might become time-consuming...

Comment: ...which brings up the idea for a hybrid approach: Storing intermediate images after a certain amount of done operations so that redoing all is not necessary when the last operation is undone. (This somehow reminds me to video compression which stores difference images to reduce memory footprint of individual images (frames) but inserts ful frames from time to time.)

Comment: Ask yourself why you want to implement it as efficiently as possible, and choose the simplest possible solution with minimal amount of code.